# graph simulation model in R

Tags: r, graph, model, simulation

I have a system which is modelled as a graph model - i.e. variables with arrows between them, similar to a classical epidemic model: http://origin-ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0933365704001678-gr4.gif (this is not my model, just an example of the layout).

I run the simulation in discrete time. There is an equation connected to each arrow (implemented now as a function for each variable, that updates the variable depending on the variables that affect it).

This type of model is so common, I was wondering whether R has a predifined syntax / package to specify such simulations? I have looked at the book "Graphical models in R", but that seems to be for a sligthly different use (mathematical solutions etc.).
Thanks!

Comment: it's not straight up r solution but you might be able to squeeze something out of it - [D3 Network](http://www.r-bloggers.com/quick-and-simple-d3-network-graphs-from-r/)

Comment: I do not think this is what I am looking for (though thanks for posting). R seems to have quite extensive capabilities for graphical models http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html but defining the graph is not the difficult part. It is rather whether someone has implemented common simulations using these graphs. It would surprise if this was not done, as this modelling approach is so common.

Comment: There is a `simulate` function in the `gRain` package, with an example in [this article](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v46/i10/).

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at it. I think I may not be using the term 'graphical model' correctly, or I do not understand the article. It seems to be about graphical models, where the arrows are conditional probabilities - e.g. the probability of developing lung cancer is the consequence of certain other variables which vary randomly, but conditionally on each other, in a network. My graphical model illustrates causal relationships (in my case, topography relates to the probability of speciation, speciation affects species richness etc.). So far I have no random variables. Does this make sense?

Comment: Is there anything random in your model or is it entirely deterministic?
If there is some randomness, somewhere, 
it looks like a graphical model --
made more complicated by the presence of time.
If it is entirely deterministic, it is not a graphical model but a [dynamical system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system), and
you can write a function, `f`, that takes the state at time t (say, a list,
with the current value of all the variables), and returns the state at time t+1.
To simulate the evolution of this dynamical system, a loop suffices.

Comment: OK, thanks, in the current implementation it is completely deterministic, and I have implemented it in R using a loop, and a special function for each causal arrow in the diagram, along with a 'step' function. It is just that this creates confusing spagetti code which makes it hard to visualise and debug the model.